# How to manage multiple client sessions within server application?

Tags: ruby, network-programming, server-side

I'm writing web chat application, similar to GTalk. It based on Orbited + Sinatra for client side, and Ruby for server side. I've already implemented all the protocol, everything working good.

But, I don't know how to deal if there are multiple connections from one user. Let's say for example, I logged to chat from 2 different browsers. Google handles that really nice, two chats appear to be exactly the same. But my app just shows 2 exactly the same users in contact list, which is incorrect.

Here is a small example of server clients pool:

```
Server
--> Connections
      |
      - Client (User Information, ConnectionID)
      - Client (User Information, ConnectionID)
      ....
      - Client (...)
```

I have 2 types of messages: Private (user-to-user), Public (user-to-conference).

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with such situation? Any suggestions?

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. XMPP is the standard for instant messanging. There are many free implementations. Google Talk is just another implementation of XMPP. XMPP is modular, so you can put your own needs into the protocol, without breaking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the vague answer, but here goes:  you need to "push" chat text out to every connection for a given user ID, not just responde to a "pull" from a given connection / session.

I don't know how your client works, but if it polls for updates, you probably need to save a per user account image of recent messages in a database, then get all the relevant updates for that user from the DB, and not just associate the chatting with "point to point" sessions.

Grr.  I don't have time to explain this better now...

- - - - update: - - - - -

Make some kind of "set" data structure for each conversation identifying the sessions (and therefore users) involved, regardless of whether it is one on one, or a large group.  Make a list of posts for each conversation, ordered chronologically, which you can scan to update the display of each client, supplying any as yet un-viewed posts.

As an aside to a comment on the question itself:  Somebody made the point that "it's been done", download the code.  Perhaps that's a valid point, perhaps not.  If you can find an existing code base in a form you can embrace and extend, great.  If not (because it's homework, or because corporate policy says "do it from scratch, here and now", well, then, downloading a "solution" is not a valid criticism, is it?

Comment: Ok, im already using server push approach. The thing is - when you log in with your account into the chat from different browser tabs - it creates another connection on server with the same user, so there are 2 or more same users on chat list. I cant figure out the best way to allocate session pool for users who have more than one connection.

Answer (score 0):

When your clients connect, you should give them a unique identifier. Classic ASP had that `SessionID` but you just need something unique, maybe sending that key back to client through a cookie.

After that, any message sent by clients should be placed in a common area; again in classic ASP you had that `Application` objects, nicely suitable for this task.

From this, you can go anywhere: implement chat rooms, filtering messages, whispering something, etc.

I did something like that about 7, 8 years ago, storing messages in XML files. But you could also use some database to do that.

As pseudo code, you'll have following for every web request:

```
    if request DON'T have cookie ID
       create an unique ID and set cookie

    process incoming action
       case "private":
            write message for that unique id
       case "public"
            write message without target user
       case ...

    display user interface
        list all messages for your unique id, or without target
        create a users list, using unique IDs as value (except yours)

    refresh every n seconds
```

Comment: No no, i got the point. But in your case if you login to your chat app from different locations with the same account you will receive messages from yourself. Right? Or i just dont see the idea of keeping uniq id for each connection.

Comment: you'll not receive messages from yourself, as second connection will have another unique id.